# Is underscore needed between the word and number in a variable name?

Tags: python, python-3.x, variables, naming-conventions, pep8

I have 2 variables, `city1` and `city2` as shown below:

```py
city1 = "New York" 
city2 = "Los Angeles"
```

According to [Function and Variable Names](https://peps.python.org/pep-0008/#function-and-variable-names) in [PEP 8 – Style Guide for Python Code](https://peps.python.org/pep-0008), an underscore `_` is needed between the words in a variable name as shown below:

```py
first_name = "John"
last_name = "Tom"
```

Now, is underscore also needed between the word and number in a variable name as shown below?

```py
city_1 = "New York" 
city_2 = "Los Angeles"
```

Comment: The PEP 8 recommendations are just guidelines, so apply as you see fit — but above all, be consistent.

Comment: There are those who would argue "1" is a word (in this context), but again style guides are just suggestions...

Comment: It's hard to tell for sure from the limited example, in your question but the answer is likely "neither one" because the cities should be put into a single container, like a list, and accessed via an index like `cities[0]`, `cities[1]`, etc (as opposed to each one a unique variable name. An except to that rule might be it they were parameters  to a function that did something related to just two of them (i.e. finding the distance between them).

Answer (score 1):

From PEP8:

> Function names should be lowercase, with words separated by underscores as necessary to improve readability.
>
> Variable names follow the same convention as function names.

So underscores are there to improve readability, but you are free to do as you want.

```py
longvariable = 0
long_variable = 1
city1 = 2
city_2 = 3
```

The main thing is to stay consistent within your code style and your organisation's style.

Answer (score 1):

Python naming conventions do not specify whether or not you need to separate numbers from letters by an underscore. This is a matter of opinion. Here is mine.

I use no separator between letters and numbers for brevity. Thus, I use:

```
city1 = "New York" 
city2 = "Los Angeles"
```

It seems that the highly scientific google search agrees:
[file:py "test1"](https://www.google.com/search?q=file%3Apy+%22test1%22): `About 712,000 results`
[file:py "test_1"](https://www.google.com/search?q=file%3Apy+%22test_1%22): `About 66,800 results`

How can 712,000 users be wrong? But seriously, that's an order of magnitude difference!

A few related notes:

- When numeric extensions are needed, use lists or dictionaries, which are more extensible, and which allow iterations, loops, comprehensions, etc - everything that can help keep the code non repetitive:

```
# Lists:
cities = ['New York', 'Los Angeles']
print(cities[0])
# New York

cities.append('Boston')
cities = [c.lower() for c in cities]
print(cities[2])
# boston

# Dictionaries:
city  = {'src': 'New York', 'dest': 'Los Angeles'}
print(city['src'])
# New York
```

- Avoid relatively uninformative extensions such as `1` or `2`, unless they are part of the knowledge domain **of the users**. For example, `read1` and `read2` have specific meaning for biologists, who are the users in the analysis of next-generation sequencing. But that's rare. And even then, lists are a better idea (because sooner than you think, there will also be `read3` and `read4`). Perhaps `src_city` and `dest_city` can be better choices and `city1` and `city2`.